# Postgresql SETOF vs Refcursor

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a basic user table in Postgresql,

```
CREATE TABLE myuser (
userId    bigserial primary key,
user_name varchar(32),
password  varchar(32)
);
```

I want a stored procedure to retrieve this data.  Looking at the documentation here:  [posgresql call proc](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html) I see I have basically 2 different options.

1. return a SETOF myuser
2. return a refcursor with the data I want

I am using Java, and I want to know which one is faster, and/or better.  What are the functional differences between the two?  I looks like the only difference is how I set up my Java CallableStatement, but why would I choose one over the other?

Comment: Do it the simplest way until you have a reason to try to get fancy. `SETOF` is simpler to work with and generally saner. Use it unless you find you have a specific reason to start jumping through hoops with refcursors.

Answer (score 4):

A main differences between cursors and recordsets is possibility to control data transport to client with cursors. Cursors are useful when you work with very large data that should be moved from server to client. Without cursors PostgreSQL push all data to client memory at once - it is fast (in total time, but start time is same as total time, and it can require lot of memory (for bigger data)). With cursors you can control how much lines you can fetch from server to client (total time is usually bigger, but start time can be (not must be - depends on more factors) low.

```
-- classic query
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100000);
-- 100000 rows is pushed to client at once 
-- less network handshaking, more client memory consumption

-- cursors - more network handshaking, 
-- controlled memory consumption on client side
BEGIN;
DECLARE xx CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1000000);
FETCH 100 FROM xx; -- read 100 rows from server to client
FETCH 100 FROM xx; -- read next 100 rows from server to client
...
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a PostgreSQL guru, but from what I know about SQL it's almost always better to work with sets than with cursors, so I'd say - go with SETOF.

There're also no stored procedures in PostgreSQL, only functions.

Comment: It is not true in all aspects. You must not use cursors for emulation ISAM access (not SQL usage). With SQL, the cursors are very practical tool, mainly for large data or for better customer expirience - you can get first N row faster and show it with cursors.